# Escape path separator in a regular expression

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I need to write a regular expression that finds javascript files that match

```
<anypath><slash>js<slash><anything>.js
```

For example, it should work for both :

- c:\mysite\js\common.js (Windows)
- /var/www/mysite/js/common.js (UNIX)

The problem is that the file separator in Windows is not being properly escaped :

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(
     "^(.+?)" + 
     File.separator +
     "js" +
     File.separator +
     "(.+?).js$" );
```

Throwing

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence
```

Is there any way to use a common regular expression that works in both Windows and UNIX systems ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Does `Pattern.quote(File.separator)` do the trick?

EDIT: This is available as of Java 1.5 or later. For 1.4, you need to simply escape the file separator char:

```
"\\" + File.separator
```

Escaping punctuation characters will not break anything, but escaping letters or numbers unconditionally will either change them to their special meaning or lead to a [PatternSyntaxException](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/PatternSyntaxException.html). *(Thanks [Alan M](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20938/alan-m) for pointing this out in the comments!)*

Comment: Great, what a pity it is only available since Java 1.5+ (I still need it to work in 1.4)

Comment: since Java 7, you can use `FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()` instead of `File.separator`

Comment: @herau Is there a difference?

Comment: @Tomalak In the case of the default provider, this method returns the same separator as File.separator. However it can be useful when you work with other provider.

Answer (score 7):

> Is there any way to use a common regular expression that works in both Windows and UNIX systems ?

Yes, just use a regex that matches both kinds of separator.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^(.+?)" + 
    "[/\\\\]" +
    "js" +
    "[/\\\\]" +
    "(.+?)\\.js$" );
```

It's safe because neither Windows nor Unix permits those characters in a file or directory name.

Comment: I like this answer more, since it works natively with all types of regular expressions both on windows and unix. For instance in ant tasks where you do not have helpers like in the accepted answer.

Comment: Actually, I think Linux would be okay with `\` in the middle of a file or directory name (and not interpret it as having anything to do with directories); it's some combinations of *users* and *filesystems* that forbid it, AFAIK. (*I* certainly don't want any files or directories with such names.)

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use a backslash to escape the path separator like so:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(
     "^(.+?)\\" + 
     File.separator +
     "js\\" +
     File.separator +
     "(.+?).js$" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you escape `File.separator`:

```
... +
"\\" + File.separator +
...
```

to fit `Pattern.compile` requirements?
I hope "/" (unix case) is processed as a single "/".

Answer (score 1):

I've tested gimel's answer on a Unix system - putting `"\\" + File.separator` works fine - the resulting `"\/"` in the pattern correctly matches a single `"/"`